# core/template block not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I am trying to add a block on my checkout page but for some reason its not working.

```
<block type="core/template" name="checkout.cart.consultant" as="consultant" template="checkout/cart/consultant.phtml"/>
```

file path

> layout/template/checkout/cart/consultant.phtml

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you place the block, because the answer depends on that?

Comment: Its on checkout.xml file in the same root folder

Comment: are you trying to add the block to checkout.xml file in the vendor directory?

Comment: Apparently i added in the wrong cart.phtml file. Still having trouble working with the folders hierarchy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should place your custom `.phtml` file in "template" and not the "layout" directory.

Custom `.phtml` file path would be:

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/consultant.phtml

And you can call the file in `XML layout file` using following:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="consultant_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/consultant.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I fixed but still doesn't show up

Comment: where are you adding the block?

Comment: Apparently i added in the wrong cart.phtml file. Still having trouble working with the folders hierarchy. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

In upgraded magento version there is new feature for security.

you have to grant permission to your `core/template` from admin.

It should be there but please double confirm `system->permission->block`

There should be row like https://www.screencast.com/t/48FBB3kSNPmM

if not please add and then it should work.

Comment: I already have granted permission from admin.